# Angular async pipe displays only the first element of array

Tags: angular, async-pipe, angular-akita, akita

I have an array of strings that i get as a value from an observable.

In the view I am trying to display the values with *async pipe*.

the template displays only the value of the last item and multiplies it in the number of recieved objects.

When I log the values to the console inside the subscribe method the results are displayed as they should be.

[image]

**component.ts**

```
hideCategories = true;
categories$:Observable<string[]> = this.categoriesQuery.selectAll();
destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>(); 

ngOnInit()
{
  this.categoriesQuery.selectedIsCategoriesLoaded$.pipe(
    filter(isLoaded => !isLoaded),
    switchMap((isLoaded) =>
    {
      return this.ticketService.fetchCategories()
    }),
    takeUntil(this.destroy$))
    .subscribe(console.log);
}
```

**component.html**

```
<ul *ngIf="!hideCategories && categories$ | async as categories" class="search-ul w-100" id="categories">
    <li *ngFor="let cat of categories" (click)="onSelectCategory(cat)" class="pointer" tabindex="0">{{cat}}</li>
</ul>
```

Not sure if it's related but I am using ***datorama akita*** for state managment.

**----Edit----**

```
this.categoriesQuery.selectAll()
```

Is derived from datorama akita QueryEntity Class.

**service.ts**

```
  fetchCategories()
  {
    return this.http.get<string[]>(environment.endpoints.tickets.getCategories).pipe(
      tap(categories =>
         this.categoriesStore.setCategories(categories, true)
      ));
  }
```

**store.ts**

```
@StoreConfig({ name: 'categories' })
export class CategoriesStore extends EntityStore<CategoriesState>{

    constructor()
    {
      super(createInitialState());
  }

  setCategories(categories: string[], isCategoriesLoaded: boolean)
  {
    this.set(categories);
    this.update(state =>
    ({
      ...state,
      isCategoriesLoaded
    }))
  }
}
export function createInitialState(): CategoriesState
{
  return {
    isCategoriesLoaded: false
  }
}
```

Comment: I feel that the problem is that in any moment (perhafs in a "map") you use the "=" instead the "==" to find or compare any object. NOTE: You don't show the this.categoriesQuery.selectAll() function, so it's difficult say. NOTE2: please not use images to show code or .html, use text. It's easy for us reply or understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that **akita** store management has to receive an Entity that has an Id field.

I was getting an array of strings from my back end and i tried to set this array to the store.

That didn't work since a **string**  is not an object with an Id property.
So what I have done is to generate in my client an object with a fake id for each string i get.

Since these objects do not change and i don't need to update/delete them this solution is good enough for me..